# Finding last transaction date in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that has `customer_id`, `order_id` and `Transaction_Date`. I want to find for a given customer, what was the last transaction date.

The output is expected to have the following: `customer_id`, `order_id`, `Transaction_Date`, `last_transaction_date`.

[image: Pandas dataframe]

Comment: `df.groupby('customer').transaction_date.min()`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Take time to read the following page on how to produce a good example to ask your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Don't paste pics, paste data directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby with transform, max or min :

**Data** :

```
d = {'customer_id':['customer1','customer2','customer1'],'order_id':[1,2,3],'Transaction_Date':[pd.to_datetime('2019-09-05'),pd.to_datetime('2019-09-06'),pd.to_datetime('2019-09-07')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
    customer_id order_id    Transaction_Date
0   customer1   1           2019-09-05
1   customer2   2           2019-09-06
2   customer1   3           2019-09-07
```

**Code**

```
df['last_date'] = df.groupby('customer_id')['Transaction_Date'].transform('max')
```

**Result**

```
    customer_id order_id    Transaction_Date    last_date
0   customer1   1           2019-09-05          2019-09-07
1   customer2   2           2019-09-06          2019-09-06
2   customer1   3           2019-09-07          2019-09-07
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can sort the data in ascending order of `customer_id` and `transaction date`

```
df = df.sort_values(['customer_id','transaction_date'],ascending = [True, True])
```

Then use the shift function

```
df['last_transaction_date'] = df.groupby('account_id')['transaction_date'].shift(1)
```

This would give you the previous transaction date for every row and null if it is the first ever transaction.